# Is it possible to upload PPT to Google drive and download as images in NODEJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api

Hi I have started using googleapis npm and can list and create a documents etc. Is it possible to upload a powerpoint doc have it saved in google drive and when I want to download it, it be downloaded as separate images. I have seen that Aspose.Slides may do it however i was hoping to be able to use google docs.

Any assistance would be awesome

My code so far is

```
var express = require('express')
  , request = require('request')
  , oauth = require('./oauth')
  , app = express();

// Setup middleware
app.use(express.static(__dirname));


// List out file that are in your Google Drive
app.get('/upload', function(req, res) {
  // Check to see if user has an access_token first
var fs = require('fs');


var  ENDPOINT_OF_GDRIVE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2';
var PARENT_FOLDER_ID = 'XXXXXXX';

var PNG_FILE = 'test.ppt';


if (oauth.access_token) {
    var accessToken = oauth.access_token;

    var fstatus = fs.statSync(PNG_FILE);
    fs.open(PNG_FILE, 'r', function(status, fileDescripter) {
      if (status) {
        console.log(status.message);
        //return;
      }

          var buffer = new Buffer(fstatus.size);
          fs.read(fileDescripter, buffer, 0, fstatus.size, 0, function(err, num) {

            request.post({
              'url': 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files',
              'qs': {
                 //request module adds "boundary" and "Content-Length" automatically.
                'uploadType': 'multipart'

              },
              'headers' : {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
              },
              'multipart':  [
                {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                  'body': JSON.stringify({
                     'title': PNG_FILE,
                     'parents': [
                       {
                         'id': PARENT_FOLDER_ID
                       }
                     ]
                   })
                },
                {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
                  'body': buffer
                }
              ]
            }, function(error, response, body){
      console.log(error);
      console.log(response);
      console.log(body);
    });

  });
});
} else {
    console.log("2nd  Could not determine if user was authed. Redirecting to /");
    res.redirect('/');
}

});

// Handle OAuth Routes
app.get('/login', oauth.login);

app.get('/auth/google/callback', oauth.callback);
app.get('/callback', oauth.callback);

app.listen(3000);
```

I have changed it from server side auth to server side oauth. I can upload a ppt and open it fine in google docs, I just need to know how to be able to download the ppt as separate images

Comment: Hi Rick, what have you tried?

Comment: I have added my code so far to the question

Comment: Through further research I changed the way I'm authenticating and can upload now, just need to convert PPT to images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THorugh a lot of research, It just can't be done yet